# Crontab syntax for non-aligned hourly range?

Tags: cron

If I want to schedule a job to occur every five minutes between 9 until 11 pm  I can use the following cron trigger:

```
0/5 21-22 * * *
```

(or something like `5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 21-22 * * *` for finer control over the minutes if needed).

Is there a way to specify "every five minutes from 9:30 until 11:30"?  The trickiness revolves around having e.g. `5` in the minutes field yet skipping it if the hour is `21`, and I'm not immediately aware of any way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, workaround would be to add more scheduled jobs in cron...

i.e.

```
30,35,40,45,50,55 21 * * *  /job_to_run
*/5 22 /job_to_run
5,10,15,20,25,30 23 * * * /job_to_run
```

p.s. Cron usually has the following order:

```
Minutes Hour DayOfMonth Month DayOfWeek Command
```

Comment: Good point, and thanks for the P.S. - I'm actually using Quartz's [cron-style trigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) so you're right, the fields were out of order.  I usually have to `man 5 crontab` each time I add a new entry anyway... :)

Comment: Your suggestion runs every 5 minutes as required, except it skips 23:00.

Answer (score 0):

```
30-55/5 21 * * * job_to_run
*/5 22 * * * job_to_run
0-30/5 23 * * * job_to_run
```

The upper limits are a bit arbitrary.  If you dislike edge cases, you could just as well use `30-59/5` and `0-34/5`.